# How to completely escape the line to call js in c# (Xamarin.Eval)?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, webview

In Xamarin have JavaScript method call. How to transfer is not illegal in the full line.
in xamarin (c#)

```
browser.Eval(string.Format("setBbCodeBody('{0}')", Vm.Item.Body));
```

And i get in js console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)

How i can full escape string?